# Custom Google-Analytics report shows no pageviews for today?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I just created a new custom report in GA with a single metric group of "Pageviews". The report shows a pageviews count on the graph for yesterday but none for today.  I have the GA Debugger plugin installed and it doesn't seem to be showing any errors or warnings. Any idea why my report isn't showing any pageviews for today? Are there any basic steps I should take to debug?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about custom reports in Google Analytics and is not programing related.

Comment: Modified titile for better readability and clearance. Added Google-Analytics instead of "ga".